# Processing Boolean in a Python List

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm using python 2 and I want to compare between item in a list but I got stucked. Here's the problem:

x = [True, False, True, True, False]

how do i get the result to process the boolean (True & False & True & True & False)?

thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the [`all` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all).

```
x = [True, False, True, True, False]
all(x)
```

The `all` function goes from left to right within an iterable, and evaluates each term in a boolean context. If it reaches any `False` (or `False`-ish, like `None`) value, it returns `False` immediately, just as if you'd written `a and b and c and d` out by hand. If it encounters only truthy values, it returns `True`.

---

Related: there's a similar function, called [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), that does the same thing using `or` instead of `and`. So in your case, `all(x)` returns `False`, but `any(x)` would return `True`, since there's at least one truthy value.

Comment: the all(x) function never cross my mind before, thanks. but now it get more complex. what if the items in the list is a pandas boolean series?

Comment: @wrez pandas `Series` objects even have their own [`all` methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.all.html#pandas.Series.all) already.

Comment: henry, it seems that you've done your little research on pandas series ;) appreciate it. if you dont mind, answering [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058254/pandas-boolean-operation-in-a-list) will cost me a lot, thanks before

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> x = [True, False, True, True, False]
>>> all(x)
False
```

I take it that by this:

> (True & False & True & True & False)

you are looking for the intersection of all Boolean values. All values in the list must evaluate to `True` for `all(x)` to return `True`.