# Pandas Boolean Operation in a Python List

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I understand that pandas dataframe type has an ability to test the logic of it's value.

here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
data = data.append({'a': 'I have data', 'b': 'no more complexe', 'c': 024204}, ignore_index=True)
data = data.append({'a': 'audoausd', 'b': '2048rafaf', 'c': 29313}, ignore_index=True)
data = data.append({'a': 'koplak ente gan', 'b': 'ente g bisa koplak', 'c': 29313}, ignore_index=True)
```

now we have the following dataframe:

```
                 a                   b      c
0      I have data    no more complexe  10372
1         audoausd           2048rafaf  29313
2  koplak ente gan  ente g bisa koplak  29313
```

test the logic value for column c and save it to a variable

```
c = data.c > 20000
```

will set c to the following value

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: c, dtype: bool
```

test the logic value for column b and save it to a variable

```
b = data.b.str.contains('koplak')
```

b value

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

and also for column a

```
a = data.a.str.contains('koplak')
```

a value

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

when i compare all of this values by doing a & b & c will return:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

it's not well fashioned to hard code in case there are many columns involve, so i try to make a list containing all columns logic

```
logic = [a, b, c]
```

how do i compare all the items automatically to get a & b & c result?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`a & b & c` is equivalent to

```
import functools
print(functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x & y, [a, b, c]))
```

which yields

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Unlike my original answer below (suggesting `np.logical_and.reduce`), I am confident `functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x & y, [a, b, c])` will faithfully return the same Series as `a & b & c`.

(In Python2.7, `reduce` is a builtin function. `functools.reduce` is the same function as `reduce`. In Python3, `reduce` was removed from the builtins and only `functools.reduce` remains. So to future-proof your code, use `functools.reduce`.)

---

Edit: Using `np.logical_and.reduce([logic])` may not work in all situations. Here is a counterexample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.Series([True,True,False,False], index=[1,2,3,4]) 
y = pd.Series([True,True,False,False], index=[1,2,3,4]) 
print(x & y)
```

prints

```
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

but `np.logical_and.reduce([x,y])` raises a ValueError

```
    print(np.logical_and.reduce([x,y]))
  File "/data1/unutbu/.virtualenvs/dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.13.0_98_gd9b0c1f-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/generic.py", line 665, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: this is pretty useful; can u do a PR to add to the cookbook ? you can use this link with a nice title/description

Comment: I had the same problem but with a logical OR (`|`) and I came up with `sum(my_list_of_serieses).astype(bool)`.